# Searching quadruplex sequence from a FASTA file by using Python

Tags: python

The quadruplex sequence of a genome looks like this:

```
Gx Ny1 Gx Ny2 Gx Ny3 Gx
```

where G is the Guanine base and the Ns are representing other bases. The x, y1, y2 and y3 are integer.

A particular segment will be quadruplex sequence if `x >= 2`.

My question is I want to count how many such segments are present in a FASTA sequence and what are their types in terms of x, y1,y2 and y3. For that purpose I need some help from your side.

Comment: Please explain your question with an example and expected output

Comment: A FASTA sequence looks like AGGGGTTTAGGGCCCCCCAAAAAGGGGGGTTTTTTTCCCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGGGGAAACCCCCCC

Basically it is a combination of A, T, G, C letter. I want to find this pattern, Gx Ny1 Gx Ny2 Gx Ny3 Gx from this sequence where G is actually letter G and N represents other letter (A,T and C). Moreover, x and y1, y2, y3 are integer and the value of x must be greater than 2, however there is no restriction on y. I need a python script that find such pattern from that sequence. The expected output should be 
1) position of G letters and the value of x, y1, y2, y3
2) total no of suc pattern

Comment: No,those are not my asking pattern. I am asking for pattern like ---(10)GGGAATGGGCGGGGGGTCGGG(31)---- in which start seq 10, end seq 31 and the length of pattern is 21. Moreover, you notice the value of x>2 and y1=3 (AAT), y2=1(C) and y3=2 (TC) in this particular pattern. So, depending on the values of x, y1, y2 and y3 there are various combinations are possible. I am looking for such pattern in long genome sequence say 10 million length.

Comment: But `x` is not constant here, is it? First there are 3 `G`'s, then 3, then 6 in a row, then 3 again. Is this allowed?